# Removing characters from the left side of a Python string?

Tags: python

How would I go about removing characters from the left side of a Python string? Example:

```
string = "Devicename MA:CA:DD:RE:SS"
```

What should I do to make a new string of just the MAC Address?

Comment: Do you know how slicing works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do different things:

```
string.split(' ')[1]
```

or

```
string[11:]
```

or

```
string[-14:]
```

both yielding

```
'MA:CA:DD:RE:SS'
```

The last option is the closest to what you want I suppose. It takes the leftmost 14 characters from the string.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the string always has the format:

```
Devicename<space>MAC Address
```

You can do this by simply splitting the string on the space and taking the second element in the resulting list.

```
>>> string = "Devicename MA:CA:DD:RE:SS"
>>> string.split()[1]
'MA:CA:DD:RE:SS'
```

---

One note - I assume you know that is not a valid MAC address, correct?